# Calculate the limitation in complex coordinate.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, complex-numbers

Can we say that this limitation is zero?!and how can we be sure that such limitation leads to a special value although we can't test all pathes through which z leads to a specific value?$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{x^2 y^6}{x^4+y^2}$ where $z = x + i y$.

Comment: Don't any of you have any idea,is the answer correct,if not please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the answer,I think for such limitation we should transform the limitation to a derivative fraction form,and check if the function that it's derivative is the so-called fraction is analytic or not.